# Statistical significance of three ovelapping samples

Tags: statistical-significance, genetics

I have three groups of biological data (gene mutations) which overlaps with each other. I have represented them in a venn diagram.
[image]

What would be the test should I use to check whether the intersection between list1 &2 is significantly different from intersection between list 1 & 3?
I'm checking whether the list 1 is more biased towards list 2 or is it the other way around.

Comment: Can you define "different"?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking here. What are you trying to compare about them?